# Add marker in google maps when user register

Tags: javascript, maps, marker

I want do that, when user register in my portal their can add marker to map( google maps). Anyone can help me how can i do that?

---

Edit:

Code i use :

```
 <script>
function initialize() {

        /* Style of the map */
        var styles = [
        {
          stylers: [
            { hue: "#00ffe6" },
            { saturation: -20 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "road",
          elementType: "geometry",
          stylers: [
            { lightness: 100 },
            { visibility: "simplified" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "road",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
             featureType: "poi",
             elementType: "labels",
             stylers: [
               { visibility: "off" }
             ]
           }

         ];


      // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
      // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
      var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: "Semini"});

      /* Lat. and Lon. of the center of the map */

      var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(45.8330653, 9.8506751,11);

      // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
      // to the map type control.
      var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 720px)" );

    if (mq.matches){
 var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,                //zoom level
        center: myCenter,       //center position
        scrollwheel: false,     //zoom when scroll disable
        zoomControl: true,      //show control zoom

        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style'] 
        }

      };

  } else {
 var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,               //zoom level
        center: myCenter,       //center position
        scrollwheel: false,     //zoom when scroll disable
        zoomControl: true,      //show control zoom

        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style'] 
        }

      };
};

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-                 canvas'),mapOptions);

      //Associate the Semini with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
      map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('map_style');


     /* Marker example for stack */
      var contentString3 = 
          '<div class="popup">'+
          '<h2 id="example">City</h2>'+
                      '<a  href="/main.php?page=city">'+
          'VISIT</a> '+
          '</div>';

      var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString3,
          maxWidth: 230,
          maxHeight: 300,

      });

      var image1 = 'mappa/food.png';
      var myLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.87901, 10.17745);
      var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng3,
          map: map,
          icon: image1
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
        infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
      });




       /* open popup marker when map is load */
      new google.maps.event.trigger( marker, 'click' );         

  }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

in that script i add static marker ok? But how can user of portal when register add marker in that code? so lat and long is marker By XXX

like that :
https://www.sofasurfer.org/blog/2011/06/27/dynamic-google-map-markers-via-simple-json-file/

Comment: Use this link for reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: @KiranMuralee i have maps, but i dont know how can user add dynamic marker

Comment: I have given an answer to your question,let me know if this was what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a marker in gmap, you should first get the location coordinates where you want to put the marker.Make sure that your map is global so that you can refer it later for adding another marker dynamically.

Simple example of using a marker in a map is given below.

```
//specify your Html element Id value here where you want to show the map
var mapPosition=document.getElementById('myMap');

//Make sure map is global so that another marker can be added to the map later
 map = new google.maps.Map(mapPosition, {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myPosition
    });

// specify your coordinates
var myPosition={lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

var markerOptions={position: myPosition, map: map, title: 'some text'};

// putting a marker in the specified position in the map
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
```

If you want to add another marker dynamically say on a button click.You can do like this.

```
//assuming this function gets called on some button click
function onButtonClick()
{
   //create your maker here
   var anotherPosition={lat: -29.363, lng: 150.044};
   var newMarkerOptions={position: anotherPosition, map: map, title: 'some text'};
   var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker(newMarkerOptions);
}
```

Comment: in function onbottunclick lat and lng is static, how user can choise in map or with adress lat and long?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you

Comment: dat my english ^^ try with gtraslate : When a user registers I wish you could choose where to place the marker on the map . for example:
If the company " X " Choose NY city will appear as a marker on the map in NY with his name

Comment: So you are telling like after user registers,they can choose the city and it should get added as a marker to the map.Try this after choosing city get the location coordinates of the city.If you are using place auto complete in gmap, you could select the city and get the gps coordinates easily.Once you get the gps coordinates,you can make use of it to create the marker.

Comment: On registration not after. can you explain me code?